# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a form article where I dispatch actions

components/form.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import uuidvl from 'uuid';
import { addArticle } from '../actions/index';
const mapDispatchtoProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addArticle: article => dispatch(addArticle(article))
    };
};
class ConnectedForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: ''
        }
    }
    handleChange(eVal, nm) {
        this.setState({ "title": eVal })
    }
    handleSubmit(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        const { title } = this.state;
        const id = uuidvl();
        this.props.addArticle({ title, id });
        this.setState({ title: '' });
    }
    render() {
        const { title } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <input type='text' value={title} id="title" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.value, 'article')} />
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const Form = connect(null, mapDispatchtoProps)(ConnectedForm);
export default Form;
```

js/actions/index.js

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
export const addArticle = article => ({ type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload: article });
```

When I click on add I get the following error

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

these lines are highlighted

```
addArticle:article =>dispatch(addArticle(article))
this.props.addArticle({ title , id });
```

stacktrace

```
                 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
                addArticle
                E:/reacr-redux/src/components/Form.js:7
                4 | import { addArticle } from '../actions/index';
                5 | const mapDispatchtoProps= dispatch=>{
                6 |     return{
                >  7 |         addArticle:article =>dispatch(addArticle(article))
                    | ^   8 |     };
                9 | };
                10 | class ConnectedForm extends Component{
                View compiled
                ConnectedForm.handleSubmit
                E:/reacr-redux/src/components/Form.js:24
                21 |     ev.preventDefault();
                22 |     const { title }=this.state;
                23 |     const id = uuidvl();
                > 24 |     this.props.addArticle({ title , id });
                    | ^  25 |     this.setState({title:''});
                26 | }                
                27 | render(){
                View compiled
                ▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
                This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
                Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

reducers/index.js

```
                import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
            const initialState={
                articles:[]
            };
            const rootReducer= ( state = initialState ,  action ) => {
                switch(action.type){
                    case ADD_ARTICLE:        
                    return {...state,articles:[...state.articles,action.payload]};
                    default :
                    return state;
                }
            };
            export default rootReducer;
```

store/index.js

```
                import { createStore } from "redux";
            import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
            const store=createStore(rootReducer);
            export default store;
```

components/list.js

```
                import React from 'react';
            import { connect } from 'react-redux';

            const mapStateToProps=  state =>{
                return { articles :state.articles};
            }
            const connectedList = ({ articles }) =>(
                articles.map(e=>(
                    <li key={e.id}>{e.title}</li>
                ))
            );
            const List= connect(mapStateToProps)(connectedList);
            export default List;
```

**Action is not a function but const** is that the issue that **actions must always be functions** to work?

Can anyone lemme know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hi @Tested, I've tried to replicate your issue but I'm having trouble. Can you post the full error stacktrace? Here's a link to a codesandbox where I have your code running and all seems well. https://codesandbox.io/s/lrrov2v8r7

Comment: @DennisMartinez Ihave update with stacktrace. should i add the reducers n store too?

Comment: Thanks, @Tested. Very interesting. The only way I can replicate this issue is if `addArticle` is either not defined in your actions file or it's not an actual function (something like `export const addArticle = ADD_ARTICLE`). Have you done any sort of refactoring where you may have forgotten to save or changed from a function to a different data type? Do you get the error in thee codesandbox above? It wouldn't hurt to add the reducers and store.

Comment: @DennisMartinez I have no idea of any refactoring as I'm learning it i dont know what do i do where is it gone wrong i'll update the reducer n store

Comment: Its not a function but const is that the issue that actions must always be functions to work?

Comment: It looks to be an arrow function from what you have posted above. Just want to make sure code hasn't change since you posted. See more on arrow functions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: @DennisMartinez nope i have change as i'm stuck here i dont have any idea how do i go forward :( n whats causing the issue difficult for me to understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184598/discussion-between-dennis-martinez-and-tested).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. After trying a huge number of variations in the code I just tried updating React and react-DOM which solved it for me.

```
npm update
```

Hopefully that helps you too